# Upgrade ADF from 12.2.1.2 to 12.2.1.3 maven issue

Tags: oracle, maven, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Recently I upgraded JDev from version 12.2.1.2 to 12.2.1.3. The first issue I discovered was about a dependency called com.oracle.commons.beanutils.commons.beanutils:commons-beanutils-1.9.2:jar.

I saw that there was a patch. I applied the patch with opatch apply and then after I run a command mvn package I get another error:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.oracle.weblogic:jms-internal-notran-adp:jar:12.2.1-3-0, com.oracle.weblogic:jms-internal-xa-adp:jar:12.2.1-3-0, com.oracle.weblogic:jms-local-adp:jar:12.2.1-3-0, com.oracle.weblogic:jms-notran-adp:jar:12.2.1-3-0, com.oracle.weblogic:jms-xa-adp:jar:12.2.1-3-0: Could not find artifact com.oracle.weblogic:jms-internal-notran-adp:jar:12.2.1-3-0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)  
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:384)  
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:205)
```

Has anyone seen this problem before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Artifacts of Orace will never be in central: ` com.oracle.weblogic:jms-xa-adp:jar:12.2.1-3-0: Could not find artifact com.oracle.weblogic:jms-internal-notran-adp:jar:12.2.1-3-0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`....

Comment: I have configured my settings.xml to download from oracle central with username and pass. I also tried by just pushing the artifacts from the jdev installation to my local .m2 repo with oracle-maven-sync plugin

Comment: Better is having a repository manager handling this otherwise the order is important...cause based on the output it is tried to download them from Central....

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my OSB project today and I have solved in the following steps:

1 - Add Oracle repositories to pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
     <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
     <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
     </releases>
     <snapshots>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
     </snapshots>
     <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
     <layout>default</layout>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
     <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
     <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

2 - Build the project and verifies if the dependencies has been downloaded

3 - In case of SSL error:

> Could not transfer from/to maven.oracle.com
>   (https://maven.oracle.com):
>         sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
>   failed:       sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>         unable to find valid certification path to requested target

3.1 - Download Oracle public certificate and save it in pem format with alias 'maven.oracle.com.pem':

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect maven.oracle.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM >maven.oracle.com.pem
```

3.2 - Import the certificate to JDK truststore, over alias 'maven.oracle.com':

```
keytool -importcert -file maven.oracle.com.pem -keystore cacerts -alias "maven.oracle.com"
```

3.3 - Verifies it everything was successfully:

```
keytool -list -keystore cacerts -alias maven.oracle.com
```

PS.: If ask any password, the default JDK cacerts password is 'changeit'.

Please, make your cacerts backup before all.